# Changing active to passive?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Given the sentence:

> They took some pictures of me in the park.

What is the passive form of this sentence? I have tried:

I was taken pictures of in the park.

Is this correct expressions in English?

Comment: The correct passive is *pictures were taken of me*.

Comment: One possibility: *"[Some pictures of me] were taken [in the park]"*.

Comment: Another possibility: *"[Some pictures of me in the park] were taken".*

Comment: Yet another: *"[Some pictures] were taken [of me in the park]".*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why don't you answer this one? Your two suggestions are very interesting ... .

Comment: @Araucaria: I haven't voted one way or the other on anything here, mainly because I think the question should be on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) in the first place.

Comment: Can I edit your question a bit? It's quite interesting. I'd like to help you get it unblocked ...

Answer (score 1):

Pictures of me were taken in the park (by them).

Answer (score -4):

*I was taken pictures in the park*, should be "I was taking pictures in the park."

Perhaps you've only *heard* it before taken and taking can *sound* very similar.

Comment: I mean passive voice. They took some pictures of me --> I was taken pictures (of). I mean is this correct?

Comment: No that's not right, maybe you can say 'I had some pictures taken,' or 'I had some pictures taken of me.'

Comment: This is not correct in any way. _I was taken pictures of in the park_ is perfectly fine, though it is not simply a passivised version of _They took some pictures of me in the park_.

Comment: The question was changed after I posted my answer - so my answer became off topic due to the change of question.